# How write code and run python's files using spaCy? (using windows)

Tags: python, windows, nlp, cython, spacy

I want to implement a new model language for spaCY.
I have installed spaCy (using the guide of the official web site) on my Windows SO but I haven't understand where and how I could write and run my future files.
Help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your question correctly:  If you only want to *use* spaCy, you can simply create a Python file, `import spacy` and run it.

However, if you want to *add things* to the spaCy source – for example to add new language data that doesn't yet exist – you need to [compile spaCy from source](https://spacy.io/usage/#source). On Windows, this needs a little more preparation – but it's not that difficult:

1. Install the [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools), which include the compiler you need.
2. Fork and clone the [spaCy repository](https://github.com/explosion/spacy) on GitHub.
3. Navigate to that directory and install spaCy's dependencies (other packages plus developer requirements like Cython) by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
4. Then run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` from the same directory. This will build and compile spaCy into the directory.
5. Make sure your `PYTHONPATH` is set to the new spaCy directory. This is important so Python knows that you want to execute *this exact version* of spaCy, and not some other one you have installed somewhere else. On Windows, I normally use this command: `set PYTHONPATH=C:\path\to\spacy\directory`. There's also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) with more info. (I'm no Windows expert, though – so if anyone reads this and disagrees, feel free to correct me here.)

You can now edit the source, add files and run them. If you want to add a new language, I'd recommend starting by adding a new directory to `spacy/lang` and creating an `__init__.py`. You can find more info on how this should look in the [usage guide on adding languages](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages).

To test if everything works, start the Python interpreter and import and initialise your language. For example, let's assume you've added `Icelandic`. You should then be able to do this:

```
from spacy.lang.is import Icelandic
nlp = Icelandic()
```